# Pycharm reporting duplicate FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory in [tmp] folder when using remote SSH interpreter

Tags: linux, ssh, pycharm, filenotfoundexception

I'm using a remote SSH server for running deep learning models, and when debugging and running, Pycharm keeps reporting errors like

```
bash: line 0: cd: /tmp/VpQ52Azu2u/Aerial-Map-Translation-main/src/pix2pixHD/deeplab_series/models: No such file or directory.
```

It creates folders in the `/tmp/` directory but there is no effect. This error will disappear when click debugging buttons multiple times, but it's highly random.

Is there anyone else who has the same problem as me? Hope for answers.

I've tried to reinstall Pycharm but nothing works.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Configurations->Edit Configurations Dropdown]

You should change "Path mappings" in Run/Debug Configurations